# SSH hangs on login, shows "cvs server" as the hung process for the user

Tags: ssh, openssh, cvs

When I attempt to log in to a CentOS box via ssh, it hangs after putting in the password. I can get in to the system via console and when i run `w` I can see "cvs server" running for the user trying to login.

```
USER    TTY   FROM       LOGIN   IDLE   PCPU   WHAT
root    pts/1 systemname 11:37   1:14m  0.00s  cvs server
```

In the secure logs it looks like it was a valid login:

```
Accept password for root from 172.0.0.17 port 53270 ssh2
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

It appears like a normal login, but it will never actually give me the prompt. I've tried restarting the SSHD service, same issues. This is a production box so im a little hesitant to reboot it. I can't seem to find anything in the log files that looks suspect.

When I run `ssh -vvv` and try to connect, it also looks fine but I never get the login message after "request accepting on channel.." Here is the paste of the end of -vvv:

```
debug2: channel 1: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 1: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 1
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 1
debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 1
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 1
```

Also, I went through the network firewall to see if maybe it was dropping packets or something, nothing like that is happening. I also tried from some other system, same issue.

I've never seen this before and can't seem to find any good info on this exact issue. Any help, most appreciated!

EDIT: I only have a root account on here and there is no `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` that I can find in root, or anywhere else. However, I do see an `cvs.sh` and a `cvs.csh`  in `/etc/profile.d/`. I did see a for loop in `/etc/profile/` that is looking for scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` to run at startup.

Here are the contents of those scripts:

cvs.sh

```
# change default from rsh to ssh for cvs command
export CVS_RSH=${CVS_RSH-ssh}
```

cvs.csh

```
# change default from rsh to ssh for cvs command
if ( "$?CVS_RSH" == 0 ) setenv CVS_RSH ssh
```

I thought maybe it was looking for `cvs` and also `server` but I don't see anything with server in the script directory.  Is there somewhere else I should be looking? All the normal places ive seen profile files, nothing is there.

Thanks!

Comment: Your .bashrc or similar file on the remote server is running some command (ie this cvs command) which is hanging. If you can't figure it out, [edit] your question to include your .bashrc, .bash_profile, or other relevant files from the remote server.

Comment: I updated my question for ya -- thank you. I can't find where there is a profile trying to run those commands other than what I have edited in my question.

Comment: So if you log in as root on the console you get a shell, but via SSH you get a hung session because of t CVS server process?

Comment: Yes -- correct. I am able to login through console just fine but hangs via ssh. When Im in the console, I check logs and navigate, just can't find what's wrong. When I run 'cvs sever' from console, it hangs as well... might be a clue.

Comment: Thanks guys -- you helped me at least verify 100% that it wasn't a profile issue. Ended up being `sshd_config` entry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the troublemaker. There was an old entry in `sshd_config` that contained `ForceCommand cvs server`. Once I adjusted the comment mark and restart the service, I was able to log in just fine.

I actually went through this file at first but didn't check everything bit by bit. Could have saved me an hour or 2 to be thorough off the bat...